# count array values from unknown key

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
            [id] => 48 
            [str] => String1 
        ) 
       [1] => Array ( 
           [id] => 48 
           [str] => String1 
       ) 
       [2] => Array ( 
           [id] => 49 
           [str] => String2 
       ) 
       [3] => Array ( 
           [id] => 49 
           [str] => String2 
       ) 
       [4] => Array ( 
           [id] => 47 
           [str] => String3 
       ) 
       [5] => Array ( 
           [id] => 47 
           [str] => String3 
       ) 
       [6] => Array ( 
           [id] => 49 
           [str] => String2 
       ) 
       [7] => Array ( 
           [id] => 48 
           [str] => String1 
       )
      );
```

I would like to get count for each ID, how many times specific ID exists in array, and get results like: `String2 count 3`, `String3 count 2` and so on...

The problem is the id can be anything, rows are fetch from database by other key.

I have tried but all I get is empty key and total count of items in array:

```
$count = array();
      foreach($results as $r)
      {
        $key = array_keys($r->id);
        $count[$key]++;
      }
```

Comment: Try looking at 'array_count_values' you may need to loop over the outer array I do not remember off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$results = array(
    array("id" => '48','str' => "string1"),
    array("id" => '48','str' => "string1"),
    array("id" => '49','str' => "string1"),
    array("id" => '47','str' => "string1"),
    array("id" => '47','str' => "string1") 
    );
$count = array();
foreach($results as $r)
{
    @$count[$r['id']]++;  // it will add no of occurances of any id
}
print '<pre>';print_r($count);
exit;
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [48] => 2   // 48 id exist 2 times
    [49] => 1   // 49 id exist 1 times
    [47] => 2   // 47 id exist 2 times
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = array();
foreach($results as $r)
{
    if (isset($count[$r['id']]) {
        $count[$r['id']]['count']++;
    } else {
        $count[$r['id']] = array('count' => 1, 'string' => $r['str']);
    }
}
```

so you have count and str in one array

also you can fetch this directly from databse

```
select str, count(id) from table_name group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Do this: Let your array name is `$array`.

```
$arr = array();
foreach($array as $val){
    if(isset($arr[$val['id']]))
        $arr[$val['id']] = $arr[$val['id']] + 1;
    else
        $arr[$val['id']] = 1;
}
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [48] => 3
    [49] => 3
    [47] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using `array_column` and `array_count_values` functions:

```
$arr = [
    ['id' => 48, 'str' => 'String1'],
    ['id' => 48, 'str' => 'String1'],
    ['id' => 49, 'str' => 'String2'],
    ['id' => 50, 'str' => 'String3'],
];

$ids = array_column($arr, 'id');
$counts = array_count_values($ids);

print_r($counts);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [48] => 2
    [49] => 1
    [50] => 1
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Answer (score 0):

make it by DB

```
select id, str, count(1) 
  from thetable 
   group by id
```